# how to make azure function use the latest code published from VS2022

Tags: azure, azure-functions, visual-studio-2022

I have a netcoreapp3.1 project with few functions.
I made changes to one function and deployed using VS 2022 but when I test in Azure, I can clearly see it is using the older code.
I tried removing then adding the function from the project.
Restarting the function app in azure and other refresh methods.

Will I only be able to get the new code if I delete and recreate the function app?
Is there another way to refresh the running code?

Comment: No, you don't have to delete and recreate everytime there is an update on the code. As you are already in the Azure environment, the best way to go is to create CI/CD pipeline for your project on [Azure DevOps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-azure-devops?tabs=dotnet-core%2Cyaml%2Ccsharp) or [Github](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-github-actions?tabs=dotnet).

Answer (score 0):

Once you have published your function to a FunctionApp throughout VisualStudio 2022 or VisualStudio Code, you can deploy updates to that function app. E.g. if you have added a new HttpTrigger, you can publish all the code including the added HttpTrigger from Visual Studio itself.

Visual Studio 2022, just a black Azure Function App for testing purposes:

1. Doubleclick on "Connected Services"
2. Then in the left pane, click "Publish"
   [image]

Visual Studio Code ([Azure Tools plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.vscode-node-azure-pack)):

[image]